# Testing Method Security, how to test @PreAuthorize("#user.id != authentication.principal.id")?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to test a method in my UserController named update which looks like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@PreAuthorize("#user.id != authentication.principal.id")
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody final User user) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.saveElement(user), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

but I can't seem to be able to access the id("#user.id != authentication.principal.id") in the test

When I remove the  @PreAuthorize("#user.id != authentication.principal.id")
the Test is green. 
I've tried adding

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"}, id={"1"})
    ...
    }
```

or other modifiers too, but it didn't work

UserController.java

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(API_PATH)
public class UserController {

    public static final String API_PATH = "/api/user";
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @PreAuthorize("#user.id != authentication.principal.id")
    public ResponseEntity<User> update(@RequestBody final User user) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.saveElement(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UserControllerTest.java

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContextConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userServiceMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void initTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"})
    void update() throws Exception {
        final String apiPath = UserController.API_PATH + "/update";
        final User user = new User();
        final String userAsJsonString = TestUtils.getObjectAsJsonString(user);

        mvc.perform(put(apiPath).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(userAsJsonString)).andExpect(status().isOk());

        Mockito.verify(userServiceMock).saveElement(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with some help from friends, the problem is solved.

One prblem was that I was trying to Test 2 Cases with one test and that the User I provided was Empty for the testMethod.

Here is my solution:

```
    @Test
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"})
void updateOwnAccount() throws Exception {

    final User user = TestUtils.createUser();
    user.setId(17);

    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    mvc.perform(put(UserController.API_PATH + "/update").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(TestUtils.getObjectAsJsonString(user))).andExpect(
            status().isInternalServerError());
}

@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"})
void updateAnotherAccount() throws Exception {

    final User userToChange = TestUtils.createUser();
    userToChange.setId(17);
    final User userToLogin = TestUtils.createUser();
    userToLogin.setId(18);

    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userToLogin, null, userToLogin.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    mvc.perform(put(UserController.API_PATH + "/update").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(TestUtils.getObjectAsJsonString(userToChange)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    Mockito.verify(userServiceMock).saveElement(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class));
}
```